# Adding Library Source into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-library

I am sorry for asking this newbie question.

I am trying to use this library in my project:
https://github.com/gfranks/GFMinimalNotifications

I would like to import the source codes and not the binary.

The github page says `Simply copy the source/resource files from the library folder into your project.`

So I tried to drag and drop these [two files](https://github.com/gfranks/GFMinimalNotifications/tree/master/library/src) directly to my `libs` folder in Android Studio.

And I went back to my Activity and try to use it in my code. But the autocomplete does not seem to recognize the library.

Any help, please?
After I copied into my libs folder.

**Importing the whole module seems to be wasteful considering the project has many assets that are irrelevant to the library itself.**

### Found the solution

I copied it to the `app/libs` folder, and then in `build.gradle` I add

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'libs/GFMinimalNotifications/src/main/java'
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Steps to add modules in Android Studio
download zip file & follow steps

[image: Follow Step first]

[image: Step second]
[image: Step third]
[image: Step fourth]

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem but I'll reward the bounty and mark as accepted since it is the closer to the solution I end up using

Comment: I m getting a problem. it says that Error: Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.

Comment: @ArpitPatel - Check it once you are importing some other directory, not a library.

Comment: it is a library (pdfViewr) and I solve it this error by adding a classpath in project level gradle.

Answer (score 6):

copy in project full package [library](https://github.com/gfranks/GFMinimalNotifications/tree/master/library)

in settings gradle add `include ':library',':app'`

in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':library')
}
```

[image]

Comment: where should I place this in my project folder/package hierarchy? Thank you for answering

Answer (score 1):

**Simple step**

1. Download full project from git and extract.
2. In android studio File -> New -> Import Module -> Browse directory you extract project.
3. Resync Gradle.

Comment: Virus the answer says I would like to import the source codes and not the binary.

Comment: It would be to big of a size because in that project it has many samples and other assets which is not needed in my project. Thank you for answering though.

Comment: When import module AS ask if you would import :library and :sample, just uncheck sample and use only :library project with all source code as you needed

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to use this we ll use 2nd method **Use binary approach**

1. Copy com.github.gfranks.minimal.notification-1.0.aar into your projects libs/ directory.
2. Include the following either in your top level build.gradle file or your module specific one:

   repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
3. Under your dependencies for your main module's build.gradle file, you can reference that aar file like so: `compile 'com.github.gfranks.minimal.notification:com.github.gfranks.minimal.notification-1.0@aar'`

---

**after do above step try to sync gradle**
if there is issue like

```
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.github.gfranks.minimal.notification" to force usage
```

then add below code in android manifest file

add below line in side manifest TAG

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

add below line above Application TAG

```
<uses-sdk
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.github.gfranks.minimal.notification"/>
```

---

finally your manifest look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.test" >


    <uses-sdk
        tools:overrideLibrary="com.github.gfranks.minimal.notification"/>

    <application... >your all code </application></manifest>
```