# Encounter build error while invoke ClusterManager from android maps utils

Tags: android, maps

As title, I encountered following build error when set mClusterManager as the listener by OnCameraIdleList

```
SetOnCameraIdleListener (com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener) in GoogleMap cannot be applied to (com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager<gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart.model.MyItem>)
```

My `OnMapReady` method is shown as below.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.clear();

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currPoint));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(currentZoom));
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mMap);
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);


}
```

If cast `mClusterManager` to `(GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener)`, it may build successfully but would encounter a runtime exception later. Is there any setting or configuration needs to be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this question, as i am facing same issue.

Comment: I tried a work-around solution which is to import library source code into my project and it worked. You may refer to the link below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380497/adding-library-source-into-android-studio. Still looking forward to the correct solution. Thanks.